# Output 50 samples closest to each cluster center using scikit-learn.k-means library

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have fitted a k-means algorithm on 5000+ samples using the python scikit-learn library. I want to have the 50 samples closest to a cluster center as an output. How do I perform this task?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If `km` is the k-means model, the distance to the `j`'th centroid for each point in an array `X` is

```
d = km.transform(X)[:, j]
```

This gives an array of `len(X)` distances. The indices of the 50 closest to centroid `j` are

```
ind = np.argsort(d)[::-1][:50]
```

so the 50 points closest to the centroids are

```
X[ind]
```

(or use [`argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) if you have a recent enough NumPy, because that's a lot faster).

Comment: Why the "-1" after your argsort?  Since you want the shortest distance and argsort defaults to ascending, shouldn't you omit this?

Comment: The "-1" in argsort is unnecessary and reverses the order as pointed out by @mdubez

Answer (score 11):

One correction to the @snarly's answer.

after performing **`d = km.transform(X)[:, j]`**,
`d` has elements of **distances** to `centroid(j)`, not similarities.

so in order to give closest `top 50 indices`, you should **remove '-1'**, i.e.,

`ind = np.argsort(d)[::][:50]`

(normally, d has sorted score of distance in ascending order.)

Also, perhaps the shorter way of doing

`ind = np.argsort(d)[::-1][:50]` 
could be

`ind = np.argsort(d)[:-51:-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the distance to center values in a list, you can use sort.

```
results = [(distance_to_center, (x, y)), (distance_to_center, (x, y)), ...]
results.sort()
# get closest 50
closest_fifty = results[:50]
```