# Retrieve 100 samples closest to the centroids of each cluster after K means clustering using R

Tags: r, k-means, centroid, subsampling

I'm trying to reduce the input data size by first performing a K-means clustering in R then sample 50-100 samples per representative cluster for downstream classification and feature selection.

The original dataset was split 80/20, and then 80% went into K means training. I know the input data has 2 columns of labels and 110 columns of numeric variables. From the label column, I know there are 7 different drug treatments. In parallel, I tested the elbow method to find the optimal K for the cluster number, it is around 8. So I picked 10, to have more data clusters to sample for downstream.

Now I have finished running the model <- Kmeans(), the output list got me a little confused of what to do. Since I have to scale only the numeric variables to put into the kmeans function, the output cluster membership don't have that treatment labels anymore.  This I can overcome by appending the cluster membership to the original training data table.

Then for the 10 centroids, how do I find out what the labels are? I can't just do

```
training_set$centroids <- model$centroids
```

And most important question, how do I find 100 samples per cluster that are the closeted to their respective centroid?? I have seen one post here in python but no R resources yet.
[Output 50 samples closest to each cluster center using scikit-learn.k-means library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795535/output-50-samples-closest-to-each-cluster-center-using-scikit-learn-k-means-libr)
Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need a reproducible example of your data:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- matrix(runif(150), 50, 3)
kmeans.x <- kmeans(x, 10)
```

Now you want to find the observations in original data `x` that are closest to the centroids computed and stored as `kmeans.x`. We use the `get.knnx()` function in package `FNN`. We will just get the 5 closest observations for each of the 10 clusters.

```
library(FNN)
y <- get.knnx(x, kmeans.x$centers, 5)
str(y)
# List of 2
#  $ nn.index: int [1:10, 1:5] 42 40 50 22 39 47 11 7 8 16 ...
#  $ nn.dist : num [1:10, 1:5] 0.1237 0.0669 0.1316 0.1194 0.1253 ...
y$nn.index[1, ]
# [1] 42 38  3 22 43
idx1 <- sort(y$nn.index[1, ])
cbind(idx1, x[idx1, ])
#      idx1                          
# [1,]    3 0.28614 0.3984854 0.21657
# [2,]   22 0.13871 0.1404791 0.41064
# [3,]   38 0.20766 0.0899805 0.11372
# [4,]   42 0.43577 0.0002389 0.08026
# [5,]   43 0.03743 0.2085700 0.46407
```

The row indices of the nearest neighbors are stored in `nn.index` so for the first cluster, the 5 closest observations are 42, 38, 3, 22, 43.

Comment: This is fantastic!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Exactly the outcome I wished for.  This is so sweet!

Comment: so am I also correct to assume that in y <- get.knnx(x, kmeans.x$centers, 5), instead of put in my training set data x, I can in fact first scale(my total data set
), and put my total dataset into that line, so it will fish out the closeast neighbours that I want from the entire dataset.

Comment: or am I just mesh things together that shouldn't be done that way @dcarlson

Comment: and lastly, sorry. in cbind(idx1, x[idx1, ]), because the x data is in fact only the numeric part of the original data, say x <- m[, -c(1,2)]. So I tried to cbind(idx1,  m[idx1, ]), it seems to work, in this way I know the actual drug label in each cluster. Is this code correct? or it will just random append idx1 to my original data m

Comment: Yes you can put in the total data set since I did not limit the search to observations actually classified. Yes you can use a different matrix/data frame as long as it has the same observations in the same order.